# Homeomorphism between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, products, quotient-spaces

I need to check the following exercise:

Let $X=[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and let $\sim$ be a relation defined by $(x,0) \sim (x,1)$. Show that $X/ \sim$ is homeomorphic to the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$.

Solution:

Consider the function $f: X \rightarrow [0,1] \times S^1$ defined as $f(\theta, t)=(t(t-1), \cos(2 \pi \theta), \sin (2 \pi \theta))$. Since $f$ is conituous, bijective and $f(0,0)=(0,1,0)=f(0,1)$ we have that $[f]:X/ \sim \longrightarrow [0,1] \times S^1$ is continuos too.

Moreover, since $f^{-1}:[0,1] \times S^1 \rightarrow X$ defined by $f^{-1}(x,y,z)=\left ( \sqrt{x-1}, \frac{\arccos y}{2 \pi}, \frac{\arcsin z}{2 \pi},  \right )$ is continuos on its and bijective on its domain, we have that $[f]^{-1}$ is continuous, hence homeomorphism.

Does it work?

Comment: It seems to work. You can [save yourself some time](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism), however.

Comment: Thanks. However, the task was to solve the problem without using the compactness.

Comment: Don't leave conditions like "without using compactness" out of your Q's.

Comment: Why a vote down? What’s wrong with my post?

Answer (score 1):

Your $f$ is not injective. For instance

$$
f(0, 1/4) = (1, 0, 3/16)
$$
and
$$
f(0, 3/4) = (1, 0, 3/16).
$$

I think you might want to look at the order of the two factors.

**NB**

The question has been changed (to yet another non-injective function) after I provided this answer. The function, when I answered, was
$$
f: X \rightarrow S^1 \times [0,1]: (\theta, t) \mapsto (\cos(2 \pi \theta), \sin (2 \pi \theta), t(t-1)).
$$

To critique this new answer, which says (I quote this because I anticipate it being changed again and again and again)

> $f: X \rightarrow [0,1] \times S^1$ defined as $f(\theta, t)=(t(t-1),
> \cos(2 \pi \theta), \sin (2 \pi \theta))$. Since $f$ is conituous,
> bijective and $f(0,0)=(0,1,0)=f(0,1)$ we have that $[f]:X/ \sim
> \longrightarrow [0,1] \times S^1$

It's worth nothing that when $t = 0.5$, the first output component, $t(t-1) = 0.5 (-0.5) = -0.25$ is not actually in the interval $[0, 1]. So this answer's still wrong.

Comment: What about replacing $t(t-1)$ with $\theta t$?

Comment: That doesn't respect the equivalence relation, because for $(\theta, t) = (1,0)$ you get $0$, but for $(1,1)$ you get $1$.

Comment: Can I suggest that you get a square piece of paper, label it with $x$ and $y$ axes, and then glue the $y = 1$ edge to the $y = 0$ edge, and then just think for a while?

Comment: If I change write the function as $f(\theta, t)=(t(t-1), \cos(2 \pi \theta, \sin (2 \pi \theta)$, I obtain a map on $[0,1] \times S^1$ which is a cylinder again and $f(1,0)=(0,1,0)=f(1,1)$, for example. Right?

Comment: You can check this as well as I can; I need to go make dinner. Seriously: grab the paper and pencil and tape and start cutting and taping.

Comment: It's still wrong; still not injective (as $t = 0.25, 0.75$ continues to show), and the codomain isn't even correct. You can keep guessing, but there are a *lot* of functions, and trying each one of them, one at a time, is a really bad strategy.